# Activity and Fragment Lifecycles and Orientation Changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have been having very odd issues with `Fragments` and orientation changes that have been causing force closes and not following a logical pattern.

I created a simple `Activity` and `Fragment` lifecycle debugging application which simply implements every step of the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) by reporting the call to the logcat.

Here are the `TestActivity` and `TestFragment` classes:

**TestActivity**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    Context ct = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.e("ACT", "onCreate called");

        ct = getApplicationContext();

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(ct);
        fl.setId(1000);

        TestFragment tf = new TestFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fl.getId(), tf, "").commit();

        setContentView(fl);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.e("ACT", "onStart called");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e("ACT", "onResume called");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e("ACT", "onPause called");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e("ACT", "onStop called");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("ACT", "onDestroy called");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.e("ACT", "onRestart called");
        super.onRestart();
    }
}
```

**TestFragment**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    Context ctFrag = null;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onAttach called");
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.e("FRAG", "onCreate called");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onCreateView called");

        ctFrag = ((TestActivity) getActivity()).ct;

        TextView tv = new TextView(ctFrag);
        tv.setText("My test TextView");

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onActivityCreated called");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onStart called");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onResume called");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onPause called");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onStop called");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onDestroyView called");
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onDestroy called");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        Log.e("FRAG", "onDetach called");
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

On initialising, the Logcat output follows the expected order (start `Activity`, when the `Fragment` is attached, its lifecycle calls happen, etc):

```
01-29 10:12:50.270: E/ACT(3321): onCreate called
01-29 10:12:50.760: E/FRAG(3321): onAttach called
01-29 10:12:50.760: E/FRAG(3321): onCreate called
01-29 10:12:50.760: E/FRAG(3321): onCreateView called
01-29 10:12:50.770: E/FRAG(3321): onActivityCreated called
01-29 10:12:50.770: E/ACT(3321): onStart called
01-29 10:12:50.770: E/FRAG(3321): onStart called
01-29 10:12:50.770: E/ACT(3321): onResume called
01-29 10:12:50.770: E/FRAG(3321): onResume called
```

But the issue is, when an orientation change occurs, the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) says that:

> When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate())

Which would suggest that it should shut down the `Activity` and its contents like the lifecycle suggests (and it does) BUT then go through the same ordered process recreating the `Activity` in the new orientation. This **doesn't** happen and it seems that the `Fragment` is attempted to be recreated and **then** a new one is created in the activity recreation.

```
01-29 10:17:52.249: E/FRAG(3321): onPause called
01-29 10:17:52.259: E/ACT(3321): onPause called
01-29 10:17:52.269: E/FRAG(3321): onStop called
01-29 10:17:52.269: E/ACT(3321): onStop called
01-29 10:17:52.279: E/FRAG(3321): onDestroyView called
01-29 10:17:52.299: E/FRAG(3321): onDestroy called
01-29 10:17:52.299: E/FRAG(3321): onDetach called
01-29 10:17:52.299: E/ACT(3321): onDestroy called
01-29 10:17:52.650: E/FRAG(3321): onAttach called
01-29 10:17:52.650: E/FRAG(3321): onCreate called
01-29 10:17:52.650: E/ACT(3321): onCreate called
01-29 10:17:53.020: E/FRAG(3321): onCreateView called
01-29 10:17:53.020: E/FRAG(3321): onActivityCreated called
01-29 10:17:53.030: E/FRAG(3321): onAttach called
01-29 10:17:53.030: E/FRAG(3321): onCreate called
01-29 10:17:53.030: E/FRAG(3321): onCreateView called
01-29 10:17:53.030: E/FRAG(3321): onActivityCreated called
01-29 10:17:53.060: E/ACT(3321): onStart called
01-29 10:17:53.060: E/FRAG(3321): onStart called
01-29 10:17:53.060: E/FRAG(3321): onStart called
01-29 10:17:53.060: E/ACT(3321): onResume called
01-29 10:17:53.060: E/FRAG(3321): onResume called
01-29 10:17:53.060: E/FRAG(3321): onResume called
```

Obviously there are plenty of solutions to solve this, but my question is **why** does this happen? Why is a `Fragment` reference maintained and recreated when it is supposed to be part of that `Activity` which is supposedly **completely** destroyed and recreated? I can justify that by `Fragment`s intentionally being separate to activities. But what was causing the issues, is **why** is the original `Fragment` attached and recreated **before** the `Activity` is? It just doesn't seem to follow the logical lifecycle that the rest of the Android process does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because the activity calls `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` before being destroyed. By default, the activity is saving the states of its fragments in this method.

Later, when the activity is re-created, the old fragments are re-created in the activity `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

You might want to check the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) to better understand this behaviour.

Comment: That's correct, thanks for that. My issues just seem to be dependant on where in the `onCreate` call I call `super.onCreate()`. Now that I know exactly why this is happening, I can work around it, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are adding the fragment again and again in activity is recreated. You can use the below code in activity's onCreate method to avoid recreation of fragment:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) 
{
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

When a config change occurs the old Fragment isn't destroyed -- it adds itself back to the Activity when it's recreated.