# Nested fragments - handle rotation change

Tags: android, rotation, nested, fragment, orientation

I have FragmentA, and FragmentB inside FragmentA.
I'm trying to restore FragmentB instance after screen rotation.
Here's onCreate method of FragmentA:

```
private FragmentB fragmentB;

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    fragmentB = (FragmentB)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());

    if (fragmentB == null) {
        fragmentB = new FragmentB();

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.paneLeft, fragmentB, FragmentB.class.getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

The problem is, findFragmentByTag always returns null, and I get two FragmentB's created on the screen  (one above the other).

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine after changing getChildFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager(), but I have no idea why.
Is it an Android bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.paneLeft, fragmentB, FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't solve the problem.
I'd like to know why findFragmentByTag is not working.

Comment: where do you override onCreate() method?

Comment: I override onCreate() in FragmentA

Comment: After orientation change Android call onDestroy() method for activity and you must save your objects in onSaveInstanceSave().See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595946/activity-and-fragment-lifecycles-and-orientation-changes). You also can handle the configuration change itself declaring in manifest( (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)). For replace fragment see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace)